# Export Related Products in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, export, related-products

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1 and i want to export the products along with the related products in the csv.In the magento export sheet i am not getting the related products column.

I had googled but not got success.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not possible out of the box. It would be possible though to run a query against your database as all the relations are stored in the catalog_product_link table and all product information in the catalog_product_entity table

```
SELECT cpe1.sku, cpe2.sku FROM catalog_product_link cpl INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity cpe1 ON (cpe1.entity_id = cpl.product_id) INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity cpe2 ON (cpe2.entity_id = cpl.linked_product_id)
```